# Layout Manager and Positioning

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, glasspane, componentlistener

- how to stick JLabel in GlassPane to rellative, floating coordinates from JProgressBar without using ComponentListener or another listener,
- is there built_in notifiers in Standard LayoutManagers that can notify about its internal state, and can be accesible for override, instead my attempt with ComponentListener and NullLayout

[image]

.

[image]

SSCCE about `ComponentListener` and with `NullLayout`

```java
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560680/jprogressbar-low-values-will-not-be-displayed
public class ProgressSample {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("GlassPane instead of JLayer");
    private JLabel label;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    private JProgressBar progressSeven;

    public ProgressSample() {
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new JButton("test"));
        frame.add(new JCheckBox("test"));
        frame.add(new JRadioButton("test"));
        // Nothing is displayed if value is lover that 6
        JProgressBar progressSix = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressSix.setValue(2);
        frame.add(progressSix);
        // but this works value is higher that 6
        progressSeven = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressSeven.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
                label.setBounds(
                        (int) progressSeven.getBounds().getX(),
                        (int) progressSeven.getBounds().getY(),
                        progressSeven.getPreferredSize().width,
                        label.getPreferredSize().height);
            }
        });
        progressSeven.setValue(7);
        frame.add(progressSeven);
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("<html>Blablabla, Blablablabla<br>"
                + "Blablabla, Blablablabla<br>"
                + "Blablabla, Blablablabla</html>");
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
                progressSeven.getPreferredSize().width,
                label.getPreferredSize().height));
        Container glassPane = (Container) frame.getRootPane().getGlassPane();
        glassPane.setVisible(true);
        glassPane.setLayout(null);
        glassPane.add(label, gbc);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ProgressSample dialogTest = new ProgressSample();
    }
}
```

Comment: `layoutContainer()` can be overridden to fire an event that could be listened by a custom layout manager for the glass pane. I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: _without using ComponentListener or another listener_ what a weird requirement, homework? <g>

Comment: @kleopatra can't I hide that ??? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how to stick JLabel in GlassPane to rellative, floating coordinates
>   from JProgressBar without using ComponentListener or another listener

My idea would be to wrap the two components in a container with the `OverlayLayout` and "play" with AlignementX/AlignementY for the relative coordinates. Then just put the wrapping container in the original hierarchy. (See my SSCCE below)

> is there built_in notifiers in Standard LayoutManagers that can notify
>   about its internal state, and can be accesible for override, instead
>   my attempt with ComponentListener and NullLayout

There is no such contract in the `LayoutManager` API, hence you can't rely safely on any such mechanism. Moreover, you will face issues with standard LayoutManager because they will take your extra `JLabel` into account in the layout.

Imagine you use `FlowLayout` and you put 1 component, then your extra `JLabel`, then another component. When you move the extra `JLabel` the last component will remain "away" from the first component and you will see a gap between these two.

If this last issue is not a problem, you could simply extend `FlowLayout` (or any other `LayoutManager`), override `layoutContainer` and place the extra `JLabel` wherever you would like.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560680/jprogressbar-low-values-will-not-be-displayed
public class ProgressSample {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("GlassPane instead of JLayer");
    private JLabel label;
    private GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    private JProgressBar progressSeven;

    public ProgressSample() {
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new JButton("test"));
        frame.add(new JCheckBox("test"));
        frame.add(new JRadioButton("test"));
        // Nothing is displayed if value is lover that 6
        JProgressBar progressSix = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressSix.setValue(2);
        frame.add(progressSix);
        JPanel wrappingPanel = new JPanel();
        OverlayLayout mgr = new OverlayLayout(wrappingPanel);
        wrappingPanel.setLayout(mgr);
        progressSeven = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressSeven.setAlignmentX(0.0f);
        progressSeven.setAlignmentY(0.0f);
        frame.add(wrappingPanel);
        label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("<html>Blablabla, Blablablabla<br>" + "Blablabla, Blablablabla<br>" + "Blablabla, Blablablabla</html>");
        label.setAlignmentX(0.0f);
        label.setAlignmentY(0.0f);
        wrappingPanel.add(label);
        wrappingPanel.add(progressSeven);
        Container glassPane = (Container) frame.getRootPane().getGlassPane();
        glassPane.setVisible(true);
        glassPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ProgressSample dialogTest = new ProgressSample();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 hmmm agree, probably answering my question ....., then better, safer could be use [JProgressBar as Container(as always for me)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18355235/714968), btw this question is based on my knowledges lacks on code posted there as my answer,

Comment: @mKorbel There is one drawback to use `JProgressBar` as a container: the progress bar will stretch over the entire bounds provided so it looks pretty weird.

Comment: bounds are side effect, caused by used LayoutManager, e.g. GBC caused the same issue for JPanel, you are right this isn't standard in Swing, quite requirements in Htlm5/JavaFX